# nodejs import file and use functions natively

Tags: node.js

How can I import/require a file, and then use the functions in the file natively?

Say I have file 1:

```
const file2 = require("./file2.js")
const text = "hello"
file2.print()
```

And in file 2 I have:

```
module.exports = {
  print:()=>{
    console.log(text)
  }
}
```

I want to be able to use functions from another file as if they were in the original file, retaining the variables and objects created in the first file, is this possible?

Comment: I'd recommend to read up about globally scoped variables

Answer (score 1):

No, the modules are separate, unless you resort to assigning your variables into the [`global`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) object and hoping that you can keep track of them without going insane. Don't do that.

Either

- pass the data you need around (the best option most of the time), or
- maybe add a third module containing the shared state you need and `require()` it from both file 1 and file 2

Answer (score 0):

No!

**But**

The regular pattern of shared context is that you create a context and share it. The most simple form of it is something like this:

```
//In file 1 -->
let myContext = {
   text: 'hello'
}

file2.print(myContext);

//In file 2 -->    
module.exports = {
  print:(ctx)=>{
    console.log(ctx.text)
  }
}
```

**However**

JS has some inbuilt support for context. Something like this:

```
//In file 1 -->
let myContext = {
   text: 'hello'
}

let print = file2.print.bind(myContext);

print(); 

//In file 2 -->    
module.exports = {
  print: function(){
    console.log(this.text)
  }
}
```

Notice the removal of the argument and changing the arrow function to a function expression.